# Manwha where the main character is part of a demonic sect and gets too much power

Tags: story-identification, novel, manga, cultivation

It’s a cultivation manwha where the main character is part of a demonic sect. He becomes quite powerful, but he gets too much power and the sect attacks him. He gets thrown off a cliff and his cultivation is severed putting him in a coma-like state. Some people find him and test him only to find that even though his connection is severed his still has a lot of latent power

Comment: Did the MC wake up? Were his memories intact if he did?